# SQLAlchemy check that column entry is in list when inserting

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to specify a column in my sqlalchemy model to only accept values that are in a predefined list (in the example below `['bar','baz']`.
Below is a minimal example of what such a model would look like

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    """Example Model"""

    # simple autoincrement primary key
    id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    # this column should be constrained to ['bar', 'baz']
    exclusive_str: str = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

I found the [check constraint](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html#check-constraint) in the official documentation, but the examples listed are super simple and don't seem to cover a use case like the above. How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Have you considered having ['bar', 'baz'] as a separate table and do relationship?

Comment: Yes, that's actually my current solution, but it seems a bit overkill in my opinion